# Change Data Capture for several tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, change-tracking, change-data-capture

SQL Server 2008.
Is it possible to create Change Data Capture (or Change Tracking)
for several related tabled in a db?
For example many-to-many relation.

How it will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used it but from the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx) I would say : yes!

prepare the db first:

```
ALTER DATABASE [yourdb] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE [yourdb]
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
```

Now enable change tracking on the required table(s):

```
ALTER TABLE [yourdb].[yourschema].[yourtable]
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
```

Query for changes:

```
IF @sync_initialized = 0
  SELECT * 
  FROM [yourschema].[yourtable] LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [yourschema].[yourtable], @sync_last_received_anchor) CT
  ON CT.[yourkey] = [yourschema].[yourtable].[yourkey]
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM Sales.Customer 
  JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [yourschema].[yourtable], @sync_last_received_anchor) CT
  ON CT.[yourkey] = [yourschema].[yourtable].[yourkey]
  WHERE (CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'I' 
  AND CT.SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION 
  <= @sync_new_received_anchor)
END
```